# MySQL Using alias in subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

having this query:

```
SELECT
  gs.PAGE,
  gs.ID,
  gs.CATALOGID
FROM pages gs
WHERE gs.ID = 404
     OR gs.ID = (SELECT
           gs2.ID
         FROM pages gs2
         WHERE gs2.CATALOGID = gs.CATALOGID
             AND gs2.PAGE = gs.PAGE + 1);
```

Should give me:

```
PAGE | ID  | CATALOGID
2    | 404 | 7
3    | 403 | 7
```

But it returns only the page with ID 404.
The Problem seems to be the alias there.

I got an ID of an page and need to get the right page as well, adding to the pageno +1.

Whats the problem?

EDIT:

Sample Data:

```
PAGE ID    CATALOGID
1    291    7
2    404    7
3    403    7
4    450    7
5    455    7
```

Comment: what are you trying to do in it?

Comment: I don't understand what your query is supposed to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  gs.PAGE, 
  gs.ID, 
  gs.CATALOGID
FROM pages gs 
WHERE gs.ID    = 404 
   OR gs.PAGE = ( SELECT PAGE + 1
                  FROM pages x 
                  where x.id = 404 
                  and gs.CATALOGID = x.CATALOGID);
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f9b5/4)

Comment: if PAGE + 1 is missing or deleted from table this will not do what OP wnats

Comment: @raheelshan, what do you mean missing if it is missing then it is returning correct data ie only 404 row.

Comment: This only works with adding a DISTINCT on gs.ID. Can u confirm that?

Comment: @frgtv10, it should work without distinct, check my sql demo link

Comment: Dont know why, but now it works. Can u explain me, why manually gs.PAGE = 3 will return me those pages from other catalog as well? The subquery returns only the page +1? Hmmm?

Comment: @frgtv10, i didn't understand, if you manually use page = 3 it should return only 2 check [this link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f9b5/6)

Comment: check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d64f/1 I added page 3 to other catalog. SQL one works, but 2 not. But SQL Subquery one returns 3, or?

Comment: @frgtv10, you are not checking catalogid, in my query we restrict that to catalogid matching 404 row.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM pages gs
WHERE gs.PAGE = 
(SELECT gs2.PAGE FROM pages gs2 
 WHERE gs2.CATALOGID=gs.CATALOGID AND gs2.ID = 404 ) + 1
OR gs.ID = 404;
```

Comment: @frgtv10, my answer is exactly same, only difference is i'm doing + 1 inside subquery

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  gs.PAGE,
  gs.ID,
  gs.CATALOGID
FROM pages gs
WHERE gs.PAGE >= (SELECT
         gs2.PAGE
           FROM pages gs2
           WHERE gs2.ID = 404)
LIMIT 2;
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77bac/1)

OUTPUT

```
PAGE    ID  CATALOGID
----------------------
2       404     7
3       403     7
```